# run batch file using parameters taken from the user

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am trying to create a batch script which will take two input parameters from the user and pass those parameters to call one script which in turn should call another script. I am new to batch scripting. I have written the below code for that but the final script fails. It does not get the parameter correctly that was sent by the user.

The flow is as follow: `userInput.bat` calls `mybat.bat`, which calls `startTask.bat`.

Code for `userInput.bat`:

```
set /p userName="Enter the userName: "
echo %userName%
set /p dateofbirth="Enter the dateofbirth: "
echo %dateofbirth%
CALL mybat.bat %userName% %dateofbirth%
```

Code for `mybat.bat`:

```
CALL startTask.bat %1 "myHouseAddress" %2
CALL startTask.bat %1 "myOfficeAddress" %2
```

Code for `startTask.bat`:

```
java -classpath joda-time-1.6.jar com.mycode.somecode.KickOffTask %1 %2 %3
```

Comment: So, did you find out in what file is the problem? Did you debug/echo the variables?

Answer (score 1):

Your script seems to work fine, unless that script is only part of your program

I've made some improvements:

- Changed `%username%` to `%user%`, as the `%username%` is a predefined variable
- Added error checking
- Added support for spaces in variables

**userinput.bat:**

```
@echo off
:query.user
    set "user="
    set /p user="Enter the username: "
    if not defined user (goto query.user) else (echo user=%user%)

:query.dateofbirth
    set "dateofbirth="
    set /p dateofbirth="Enter dateofbirth: "
    if not defined dateofbirth (goto query.dateofbirth) else (echo dateofbirth=%dateofbirth%)

call mybat.bat "%user%" "%dateofbirth%"
```

**mybat.bat:**

```
@echo off
call startTask.bat "%~1" "myHouseAddress" "%~2"
call startTask.bat "%~1" "myOfficeAddress" "%~2"
```

**startTask.bat:**

```
@echo off
java -classpath joda-time-1.6.jar com.mycode.somecode.KickOffTask "%~1" "%~2" "%~3"
```